# How to get the Original Prototype Chain on given function?

Tags: javascript, prototype

`charCodeAt` is a property of `String.prototype` so `String.prototype.charCodeAt`

Given below function,

```
const foo = "whatever".charCodeAt;
```

Is there any way to automatically know foo function in fact is `String.prototype.charCodeAt`?

I've looked everywhere.  All I see is a brute force way.

Comment: Well if I create a different object `const X = { cca: String.prototype.charCodeAt }`, should the answer to "*What is `foo`?*" change to `X.cca` then? No, you cannot know which object(s) the function might have been a property of, what you're given is just a standalone function. Not a reference to a method.

Comment: @Bergi Believe me. I have worked with hard stuff and there has to be given JS reflection abilities.

Comment: Believe me, this is just how it works. Another example: after executing `String.prototype.example = String.prototype.charCodeAt;`, there is no way to know whether the `foo` value comes from `"whatever".charCodeAt` or `"whatever".example` - it's exactly the same function object. (Not talk about `"somethingElse".charCodeAt`…)

Comment: @Bergi I was thinking about recursively traversal using "this" keyword. Tired to do it using define getter on the method but I can't get no where

Comment: This is what I did but it logs the function ->     X.cca.__defineGetter__('test', function() { console.log(this) })

Comment: Essentially,  this.this.this.this.this.this

Comment: The `this` keyword is dynamic, its value is determined when you invoke a method. There is no "traversal" you can do with it. Really, what you trying to do is not possible other than "search through all known objects". But if you tell us about your actual problem, we might be able to suggest an alternative.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you're asking, so I might not be much help. The following options may or may not be what you're looking for.

- `"whatever".charCodeAt === String.prototype.charCodeAt`
- `"whatever".constructor === String`
- `"whatever".__proto__ === String.prototype`
- `typeof "whatever" === 'string'`

Comment: I want to get this String.prototype.charCodeAt as an reference given "whatever".charCodeAt input. I couldn't find a function or method in Javascript world that do it. The only method I know of is brute forcing, going over each huge gigantic table of native functions .. JS as far I know has powerful  reflection abilities. I'm sure there's a way.